# Laravel Socialite How to keep variables in session after redirect to provider

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-socialite

Welcome
I am developing a multi-lang website, I am currently logging in using social media ([Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/socialite))
**The problem is:**
Before logging in with Google, I save a variable `locale` in the session ('en', 'fr'.. etc).
but after logging in and redirecting from Google to my site, I find that the value of the variable that I put in the session is `null`
Using the following code

```
    /* this method will redirect user from my website to google for auth */
    public function redirectToGoogleProvider()
    {
        Session::put("locale", app()->getLocale());
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    /* this method will called when auth finished */
    public function handleGoogleProviderCallback()
    {
        $locale = Session::get('locale');
        dd($locale); // output: null
    }
```

**edit**: I got the same problem with using `cookie`
thank you.

Comment: did you find a solution? same problem here with Apple login.

Answer (score 0):

You can send session data with the with() method before redirection:

```
return Socialite::driver()->with(['data' => $data])->redirect();
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite#optional-parameters